# how to load/boostrap ongoing jobs with a quartz jdbcStore

Tags: quartz-scheduler

I am working to migrate from Quartz 1.6 to 2.1 and use a JDBCJobStore.    Previously, the the jobs were loaded via an xml file when the webapp started.   The scheduler is now running using the JDBCJobStore but I don't understand how to add the jobs to the database which need to run on an ongoing basis (not one-off jobs).

My first thought is to create a servlet which runs on startup which adds the jobs to the database. But my concern is that this will be executed every time I need to restart the app and the jobs will get duplicated.

Thanks,
steve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Jobs wont disappear from the database when you do a restart. So within your servlet, when it starts up before adding any jobs check to see if they already exist. When you create your jobs you can give them identities. Using the identities and some quartz methods you check if they already exist.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the memory based scheduler is a better fit for these fixed jobs.  You can create more than one scheduler, one memory, one JDBC if that makes sense for your application.

Comment: I'm using this in a cluster so I think I'm limited to JDBCJobStore